# Get result sql from Prepared Statement by Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

I'm looking for posibility to get result sql (with injected parameter) from prepared statement in java for Oracle implementation.

By MySQL the method `toString()` get wanted sql over the method `asSql()` from `com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement`.

But by Oracle implementation `oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper`, I can't find the way to get a result sql.

Comment: I have a feeling there's no such thing in Oracle driver. You might end up doing it yourself (write a wrapper around Oracle's PreparedStatement?)

Comment: if I understand you right, the way would be to inject my wrapper and build SQL self - well, replace the properties with a values?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's no such thing with the `OraclePreparedStatement`.

If you **absolutely need** that feature, you could wrap some code around the PreparedStatement I guess:

```
public class LoggingPreparedStatement implements PreparedStatement {

    private PreparedStatement delegate;

    private String sql;

    private Map<Integer,Object> parameter = new TreeMap<Integer,Object>();

    public LoggingPreparedStatement(Connection con, String sql) throws SQLException {
        this.sql = sql;
        this.delegate = con.prepareStatement(sql);      
    }

    @Override
    public void setString(int parameterIndex, String x) throws SQLException {
        parameter.put(parameterIndex, x);
        delegate.setString(parameterIndex, x);
    }

    //What you asked for
    public String getSQL() {
        String returnSQL = sql;
        //TreeMap returns sorted by key
        for(Object o : parameter.values()) {
            //Replace first ? with the value
            returnSQL = returnSQL.replaceFirst("\\?", o.toString());
        }
        return returnSQL;
    }

    //Lots of other methods to implement and delegate to original statement
    [...]
}
```

You would then instead of

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Need to change to

```
LoggingPreparedStatement ps = new LoggingPreparedStatement(con, sql);
```

So overall the process is quite painful.

Comment: What do you think about difference between integer and char parameter. Is it not required to suround char parameter (and date parameter) with apostrophe?

Comment: Of cause you can add extensive `instanceof` checks to all parameters and then adjust the printout to add that. But this is for "this is the query that was submitted" log output only, right? You won't try to execute the query printed by this statement?

Comment: I need it for debugging. When the sql-statement throw error, I would take it and run in DbVisualizer to simplify the debugging.