# Print SQL query from PreparedStatement to console in Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, tostring

I am using `PreparedStatements`.

When I am try to print the query by using `stmt.toString();`, it prints following to console,

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementJavassistProxy
```

How can I print my query?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34412289/get-result-sql-from-prepared-statement-by-oracle/34413581#34413581

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683214/get-query-from-java-sql-preparedstatement

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar but not identical issue; I'll post my solution here in case it will be useful to others:

when I did `System.out.println(stmt.toString());` I would get:

> "HikariProxyPreparedStatement@172796470 wrapping com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement@268fac52: SELECT . . . (rest of query here)"

but after some experimentation I changed it to

```
System.out.println(stmt.unwrap(com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement.class).asSql());
```

and now I get just the query.  The unwrap() method returns the underlying JDBC PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the `toString()` behaviour of a PreparedStatement is implementation-specific: [Get query from java.sql.PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683214/get-query-from-java-sql-preparedstatement)

Looks like what you've got is actually part of HikariCP's prepared statement cache, which wraps the JDBC driver's own PreparedStatement.  To get the string out of it you'd need to access the underlying PreparedStatement and hope you're using one of the drivers that supports this.  (I'm having trouble figuring out if this is possible, looks like this area of HikariCP has been substantially refactored: [github](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/ProxyPreparedStatement.java))